# is there any way to make remote desktop client using channel API GAE?

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine, remote-access

I have read about Remote Desktop Client with AngularJS and Yeoman.It is using sockets internally.

http://blog.mgechev.com/2014/02/08/remote-desktop-vnc-client-with-angularjs-and-yeoman/

As my angular app is deployed on GAE and I have implemented channel API for notifications. So is there any way to use channel API for the same?
Or any other best way to do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is: No, the approach documented by the provided link will not work on "normal" app engine.

Here a couple of reasons:

- It uses a continuous socket connection to connect to the VNC server
- It uses server sockets* to provide a stream to Yeoman VNC
- The Channel API is not an appropriate replacement for sockets

*) App Engine doesn't allow you to open listening sockets. Having the 60 second / 10 minute deadlines in place it wouldn't be practical anyway (unless manually scaled and thus taking all the good out of app engine)

I just wrote an extended answer on a slightly similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35055118/). Some of the points there could be of interest to you.

Consider using **App Engine Managed VM**. I believe you can also run [node.js application on managed vms](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/).